Notification of workflows
I have a Power Automate workflow that posts messages to a Teams channel using an Adaptive Card. It posts to the channel correctly, but the Activity Feed and the mobile notifications only say Card. I've tried adding the "summary": property above the body section (example below), but that didn't do anything. I'm using the "Post with adaptive card in a chat or channel" action. This also occurs on the "Reply with adaptive card in channel" action. Can Summary or another property be used that can be fed static text or a variable so we're not shown unhelpful "Card" notifications on our phones and Teams feed? Thanks.
Adaptive card JSON:
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"summary": "Summary text of goodness",
"body": [
{
...etc
image
please tell me some solutions.

Currently there is no way to change the preview for the messages (in the notification popup and Activity screen) sent by workflow. It will show as 'Card' which is by design.

I understand the issue you're facing with the notifications in the Activity Feed and mobile notifications only showing "Card" instead of more meaningful text. I encountered a similar problem, and here’s a workaround that might help:
Instead of using the single "Post an adaptive card to chat or channel" action, try breaking the process into two steps. This way, you can control what shows up in the notification while still using the adaptive card.
Step 1: Use the "Post a message to a chat or channel" action. This sends a standard text message that will appear in the Activity Feed and mobile notifications. You can include static text or variables in the "Message" field, and this text will appear in the notification, not just "Card." Configure it as shown below:

Step 2: After that, use the "Update an adaptive card in a chat or channel" action to actually post your adaptive card. This step updates the message with the adaptive card content without affecting the initial notification. Set it up as shown here:

Linking the Steps: In the "Message ID" field of the second action, use the Message ID from the first step to ensure PowerAutomate knows which message to update. You can select the Message ID through dynamic content, as shown here:

and here:

By splitting the actions, the notification in both the Activity Feed and on mobile will display the text from Step 1, and then the message will be updated with the adaptive card. This way, you’ll avoid the "Card" notification issue.
Final result:


Currently there is no way to change the preview for the messages (in the notification popup and Activity screen) sent by workflow. It will show as 'Card' which is by design.
